# OSGB36 to WGS84 reprojection 'error'

Tags: qgis, kml, coordinate-system, wgs84

I am a recent convert to QGIS.

I have surveyed (and corrected) DGPS (vector point) data collected to OSGB36 (British National Grid); these positions match acceptably well with the OSGB36 map layers to which I have access when imported as CSV and converted to SHP in QGIS, projected using EPSG:27700 (~1m error, although error could be in map layer which is suspect).

I'm attempting a four-stage export from QGISv1.7.4 to Google SketchUp (SU) via Google Earth (GE), as follows:

stage 1: In QGIS, Save as../KML with CRS set to WGS84 EPSG:4326 (or ETRS89);
stage 2: Open KML in GE;
stage 3: Save as KMZ;
stage 4: Open in SU.

Unfortunately, the exported WGS84 positions in the KML file are in error by ~8m - I've checked them against OSTN02 conversion using tool on [OS website](http://gps.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/convert.asp) , I've also checked GE projection (by eye: converting GE lat/long to OSGB36 and comparing with OSGB36 vector map layer).

SU fails to open the KMZ file as well, but that's not a QGIS issue, I imagine.

So the evidence seems to point towards an error in the transformation from OSGB36 to WGS84 in stage 1, i.e. with QGISv1.7.4.

Do you have any suggestions as to where the fault in my process might lie, or to an alternative approach?

Comment: A question about the coordinates in your original CSV file. Were these read out of the GPS receiver as National Grid coordinates, or as WGS84 lat/lon coordinates?

Comment: The rover and base station GPS data (presumably WGS84) were post-processed to DGPS using OS RINEX station corrections to produce National Grid eastings and northings with height AODN.

Comment: Ah, you're using professional kit. Taking readings of OS eastings and northings off the screen of a recreational GPS receiver can lead to discrepancies of about eight metres (this grade of instrument doesn't do the transformations very accurately). Perhaps it might help if you posted the data for a few of your points.

Comment: OSGB36_mE_obs,OSGB36_mN_obs,GPS_ht_obs,ht_mAODN,label,KML_lat,KML_long,OS_lat,OS_long,OS_GPSht  
277014.8215,720032.2866,126.2391,72.5446,remed1,56.3566399801,-3.9920204605,56.35657627,-3.99198303,126.239  
277024.1095,720037.1405,126.1231,72.429,remed2,56.3566859775,-3.9918725155,56.35662226,-3.99183509,126.123  
277030.6197,720044.4488,126.2305,72.5367,remed3,56.3567532905,-3.9917706459,56.35668957,-3.99173322,126.231  
277033.6013,720056.2183,126.1593,72.4657,remed4,56.3568597428,-3.9917279344,56.35679602,-3.99169052,126.159  is that legible?

Comment: ~7.5m error in KML & OSTN02 lat/long positions

Comment: I must be careful here, but I think there might be a problem with the Proj4 parameter string that QGIS is using for EPSG:27700. Would you test this by making a custom CRS using these parameters? '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs' (drop the single-quotes)

Comment: I'm able to reproduce your problem. See: http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/OSGB-coordinates-to-WGS84-lat-lon-problem-td4965339.html

Comment: To get QGIS / Proj4 to use OSTN02 instead of the lower accuracy seven parameter transformation it looks like you'll need to download the gsb file from [here][1], add it to the Proj4 directory and then reference it in the proj definition as documented [here][2].

  [1]: http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/gps/osnetfreeservices/furtherinfo/ostn02_ntv2.html
  [2]: http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms#nadgrids-GridBasedDatumAdjustments

Comment: Question is exceptionally well written and clear. It also has a comment from Andy Harffot that is very likely too be correct solution, too bad it wasn't written as answer. Even so I'm flagging for closure as there have been many coordinate system and transformation improvements in Qgis and Proj since 2012 and v1.7.