# Problems with CRS in Qgis

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Raster incorrectly reprojected to OSGB(27700)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40461/raster-incorrectly-reprojected-to-osgb27700)

The crs is clearly off when the gridlines run straight and the map lines run at an angle.

I have set the crs to match the project crs, enabled on the fly projections and nothing.

Only thing that happens is it automatically produces a custom crs to produce this off centre projection.

[image]

Comment: Which CRS are you working with? Where's the data from? Can you share it? So far we don't have enough information to help.

Comment: Hey, using ESPG: 27700 OSGB 1936.  The data is paid data so cannot share it. It is british geological survey data and osgb data.

Comment: I see. 27700 seems to be causing trouble lately. Compare http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40461/raster-incorrectly-reprojected-to-osgb27700

Comment: It seems to be the same problem that i have had before.  it sorted itself out by itself once before so hoping for the same thing to happen again.

Comment: I'll close this as a duplicate since it seems to be the exact same problem.