# Projection 27700 in the OpenGeo Suite SDK GXP

Tags: coordinate-system, boundless-suite, sdk

I have some data stored as UK grid references, they display just slightly off alignment on the map after I followed the OpenGEo EXP tutorial using these settings (below) however when I change the EPSG to 27700 for UK grid reference, my map view loads with no layers, or tools visible.

I know it displays ok using 4326 however I thought It is best to follow good practice and amend the projection to the correct EPSG.

```
  // map and layers
map: {
    id: "mymap", // id needed to reference map in portalConfig above
    title: "Map",
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: [358, 54],
    zoom: 6,

        layers: [{
        source: "ol",
        type: "OpenLayers.Layer.WMS",
        args: ["World map", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'}],
        group: "background"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [capabilities of the osgeo server](http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?request=getcapabilities&service=wms) you will see it supports just three projections:

> ```
> <SRS>EPSG:4269</SRS>
> <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
> <SRS>EPSG:900913</SRS>
> ```

None of which are epsg:27700 - so you can't ask it for a map in 27700, this is why you don't get a map.

You'd need to check the log file and/or firebug to see why you don't get any tools though, I'd guess a typo in the file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are several definitions out there for EPSG.27700. I have listed the circumstances here: [Raster incorrectly reprojected to OSGB(27700)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40461/raster-incorrectly-reprojected-to-osgb27700)

Just to give you an idea why your data was slightly shifted in the first place.

I'm not sure which definition is currently used by OpenGeo suite.