# proj/pyproj converted coordinates offset

Tags: python, coordinate-system, convert, proj

I'm using pyproj to convert some coordinates from WGS84 to OSGB36. When mapped out the converted and unconverted don't map to the same places on a map. The OSGB36 coordinates are mapped about 100 meters north west of where they ought to be.

Does anyone know what might be wrong here?

Here's an example of what I'm doing in code

```
import pyproy
wgs84=pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")
osgb36=pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:27700")
row = pyproj.transform(wgs84, osgb36, lng, lat)
```

Comment: There is a known issue with PROJ4 and OSBG36. See this link for more info:  http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gvSIG-and-OSGB36-EPSG-27700-td4104156.html

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of a fix for this?

Comment: Take the proj.4 parameters from https://epsg.io/27700, or see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40461/raster-incorrectly-reprojected-to-osgb27700 for more insight on possible datum shift values for the UK.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend upgrading to pyproj 2.2.0 as it should take into account the datum shifts.

https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/v2.2.0rel/examples.html

```py
>>> import pyproj
>>> pyproj.__version__
'2.2.0'
>>> pyproj.CRS("EPSG:27700")
<Projected CRS: EPSG:27700>
Name: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: UK - Britain and UKCS 49°46'N to 61°01'N, 7°33'W to 3°33'E
- bounds: (-9.2, 49.75, 2.88, 61.14)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: British National Grid
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: OSGB 1936
- Ellipsoid: Airy 1830
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich

>>> transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:27700")
>>> transformer.transform(2, 50)
(7200256.173104358, -5167123.170735249)
```