# Differences in the longitude and latitude between a LiDAR DSM and an optical image

Tags: coordinate-system, lidar, wgs84, envi, epsg

I've downloaded the UK's `LiDAR` elevation data (see below) in `laz` format for a specific region (Tewkesbury) from: http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey#/download

[image: LiDAR data]

From that, a `DSM (Digital Surface Model)` was generated using `ENVI LiDAR` in `ENVI (hdr)` format as shown below (the red cross represent the coordinates of the building of interest):

[image: DSM image]

By comparing the previous `DSM` image (in the `British National Grid` EPSG:27700 projection) to the optical image of the same area found on `Google Maps` (see below), I noticed that the same point appears at different locations.

[image: Optical image]

Now what I would like to do is to `co-register` the elevation `DSM` data with the optical image (or potentially a `radar` image), but this seems as an additional difficulty besides the differences in the resolution.
How can I deal with the differences in the projection between the two images? Should I (if possible) project the `DSM` elevation data to the standard `WGS84`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your data. It is just the fact that OS still issues coordinates in OSGB36, while Google uses WGS84:

[image]

So you have to assign EPSG:4277 to your degree coordinates, or EPSG:27700 for raster data in projected coordinates. Make sure that both projections have a `+towgs84' datum shift.

Comment: Which of the `WGS84` and the `EPSG:27700` is the more accurate? and where should I add the datum shift `+towgs84`?

Comment: Both are equally accurate, but have different opinion of where the zero meridian is. The datum shift is part of the projection definition, the implementation is depending on the software you use. There are different shift datasets around, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40461/raster-incorrectly-reprojected-to-osgb27700 for an overview.

Comment: Can you explain in more details how to `reproject` the `LiDAR data` from `EPSG:27700` to `WGS84` using `QGIS` or `ENVI`...?

Comment: In QGIS: `Raster -> Projections -> Warp` selecting a different filename and target CRS.