# Difference in the elevations for the same building on two DSMs saved in *.asc and *.laz formats

Tags: dem, lidar, united-kingdom, esri-ascii-raster, laz

The following question concern the same type of data as the one I've asked in [Differences in the longitude and latitude between a LiDAR DSM and an optical image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/197521/52163).

Basically, I've downloaded a tile of the `DSM` for the UK from [UK Survey Open Data](http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey/index.jsp#/survey). The `DSM` is available under two extensions: `*.laz` or `*.asc` files.

The thing I cannot understand is the difference in the elevation values between these two types of data. Below are the two `DSM` files together with the elevation of the rectangular building seen in white. Note that the `*.asc` file was opened with `QGIS` and saved in `GeoTiff` format while the `*.laz` files was opened using `ENVI LiDAR` and processed to produce the `DSM` from it. The elevation of the building in each image was retrieved roughly from its pixel intensities in the produced `GeoTIFF` images.

***.asc 2014 DSM, 100cm resolution (file: LIDAR-DSM-1M-2014-SO83/dsm_d0177253_20141212_20141212_mm_units.asc)**

*White building elevation*: around 25m.
 [image: *.asc DEM]

***.laz 2014 point cloud, 100cm resolution (file: LIDAR-LAZ-2014-SO83/SO8832_P_9938_20141212_20141212.laz)**

*White building elevation*: around 75m.
[image: *.laz DEM]

**Update1:**

- The `*.asc` files was downloaded directly from [UK Survey Open Data](http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey/index.jsp#/survey), and used as is with no further processing on my part.
- The only processing I carried out on the `*.laz` files was to open it with `ENVI LiDAR` and to produce a `DSM` in the `GeoTIFF` format (menu `Process > Process Data...`, tick only the `dsm` checkbox) from the given `*.laz` point cloud (The `Export Coordinate System` was changed to `Geographic Lat/Lon`).
- To follow the terminology in [DSM vs DTM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5704/52163), both `*.asc` and `*.laz` correspond to a `DSM` and not a `DTM` as in both cases the buildings were not flatten. a `DTM` is available on [UK Survey Open Data](http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey/index.jsp#/survey) where you can clearly see that the location where the building is supposed to be is almost the same elevation as the ground near it.
- The tile in the screenshots is `SO83`. It's in the city of Tewkesbury (Gloucestershire, England).
- The (latitude, longitude) of the building are (51.999409, -2.162770), in case one needs to visualize it on `Google Earth`.

**Update2:**

In order to investigate what had caused the differences in the heights between the two files (`.las` and `.asc`), I tried normalizing the `.las` file (the uncompressed version of the `.laz` file) using a software called `Fusion`, as described in [Normalizing point cloud data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/113125/52163):

- Since the `DTM` is available in `.asc` format, it needs to be converted first to `.dtm` format so that it could be given as an input to the second `Fusion` command. Below is the command I typed on the prompt (The `*.asc` is the input file, and the `*.dtm` is the output file):

```sh
ASCII2DTM <my-folder>\lidar.dtm m m 1 10 0 0 <my-folder>\dtm_f0177253_20141212_20141212_mm_units.asc
```

- The previous command worked well, but not the one that actually normalized the `.las` file (i.e. flatten the ground):

```sh
ClipData /height /dtm:<my-folder>\lidar.dtm <my-folder>\SO8832_P_9938_20141212_20141212.las <my-folder>\normalized-lidar.las
```

**Update3:**

This update concerns a difference in the georeferencing between both `.asc` and `.laz` files.

- If I convert both `.asc` and `.laz` files to the `GeoTIFF` format as explained above, and I open them with the `Sentinel Application Platform (SNAP)` to put a `Ground Control Point` in one of them, it doesn't match the same location in the other. Something might be responsible for the differences in the georeferencing!
- If I add the `minX, minY, maxX, maxY` arguments to the previous command `clipData` by taking these coordinates from the provided `.las` file (in `ENVI LiDAR`) I get the following error: `No input tiles overlap the sample area: (556547.00,5759837.00) - (558568.00,5761855.00).`

Comment: Maybe related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/what-is-the-difference-between-dem-dsm-and-dtm

Comment: I suspect that the .asc dataset has been normalized whereas the .laz dataset has not. That is to say, the asc dataset shows elevation above ground level and the laz dataset shows elevation above sea level.

Comment: @AndreSilva I tried decompressing the `.laz` point cloud using `LASzip` (to get the `.las` file) as you requested, and producing the `DSM` using `ENVI LiDAR` with the `.las` as an input, but I'm still getting the same elevations values as with the `.laz` file. I will try normalizing the point cloud and let you know if that's the issue

Comment: Following Aarons comment, I assume that the .asc file was created different from your way with ENVI; maybe using a different set of points, or an earlier survey.

Comment: @AndreJ Actually I downloaded the 2014 surveys for both the `*.asc` and `*.laz` files which have a resolution of 1m. But you might be right in that the processing of the `*.asc` is different from mine with `ENVI LiDAR`.

Comment: @AndreSilva I've followed the steps described here [Normalizing a Point cloud](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/113125/52163), but it's complaing about the output file that's not existant. I've updated my question (see update2), could you see if there is something wrong with the commands I typed?

Comment: It should have worked. Never tested "ClipData" without the MinX, MinY, MaxX and MaxY arguments before, but according to Fusion's manual it should work without them (the brackets [] suggest they are optional). But just to be sure, make a test using these arguments. Did you open the .dtm file in Fusion Viewer to inspect if the surface really exists, if coordinates are ok, if there are no holes, etc.? Also, have you checked if your LiDAR point cloud is in projected coordinates (usually, las files are given in projected coordinates)? And also, verify if the .dtm and the .las have same CRS?

Comment: @AndreSilva I believe both `.las` and `.asc` files are projected in the `British National Grid (EPSG:27700)`. Regarding the visualization of the `.dtm` file, I opened it with `<fusion-dir>/pdf.exe` but it doesn't really look like the original `DTM` from which it was produced, which makes me think that the parameters given to `ASCII2DTM.exe` were wrong. Also, among the parameters of `ASCII2DTM.exe` (coordsys, zone, horizdatum, vertdatum) some seem to be specific to North America and I'm not sure that this command would work with any `DTM`, does it?

Comment: Yes, it would. I have run this command with DTMs/projections from the south hemisphere (such as SAD69, SIRGAS2000) and it works ok. Do the following: where you wrote: "m m 1 10 2 2", write: "m m 1 10 0 0". It means the horizontal and vertical datum will be unknown for the software. It should work.

Comment: @AndreSilva even by modifying the parameters of `ASCII2DTM` to `m m 1 10 0 0`, I still get the same `DTM` shape in `fusion viewer (pdq.exe)` and the subsequent operation (`ClipData.exe`), as previously, complained about the nonexistence of the output file (which is normal). Here is briefly the error message it returned: `Can't open sample file <my-folder>\normalized-lidar.las`.

Comment: I ran out suggestions considering this workflow; the problem could be that the dtm and the point cloud are not overlapping, so there is no ground to be subtracted in the point cloud (the return elevation [minus] the corresponding dtm pixel elevation). To eliminate this option open the .dtm and .las with one LiDAR data viewer (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/ways-to-visualize-multiple-large-lidar-tiles) and check if they overllap. Also, did you try using the Min and Max arguments for x and y in `ASCII2DTM` as I commented before?

Comment: @AndreSilva You might be right about the "no-overlap" problem. I did add the `minX, minY, maxX, maxY` argument to the `clipData` (not to the `ASCII2DTM`, guess it was just a typo...), by taking these coordinates values with `ENVI LiDAR` from the `.laz` file. Guess what, the `clipData` command worked without an error, but I got this message on the terminal: `No input tiles overlap the sample area: (556547.00,5759837.00) - (558568.00,5761855.00)`.

Comment: Another thing I observed with `SNAP (Sentinel Application Platform)` software, when I opened the `GeoTiff` files produced from the `dtm.asc` and the `point-cloud.laz` files using `QGIS` and `ENVI LiDAR` respectively (as explained in my orginal question), if I put a `Ground Control Point` in one image it doesn't really match the same location in the other. I wonder what's causing this difference in the geolocation?

Comment: @AndreSilva The heights were simply calculated from the pixel intensities of the white building on both produced `GeoTIFF` images (I've updated the original question).

Comment: Ok, that is right. I think you could update the "Update 2" too.

Comment: From the latlong coordinates you gave above, EPSG:27700 OSGB36 coordinates should be X=388922 Y=233453. Your extent rather seems to be UTM 30N.

Comment: @AndreJ Is there a difference in the projection between the two files (`.asc` and `.las`)? I tried opening the `.asc` file with `Arcmap` earlier and it complained about the absence of a spatial coordinate system (no projection).

Comment: I have only looked into the DSM and DTM .asc files. They have no CRS information, but the coordinates in the header are in the range of EPSG:27700, and assigning that CRS the files fit to an OSM background.

Comment: @AndreJ The `.las` file when opened with `ENVI LiDAR` shows that the input datum is `WGS84` and that the zone is indeed `30N` (whereas the `.asc` file is in the `British National Grid`). Is it necessary to change the `Coordinate Reference System` of one of the two files in order for to be comparable?

Comment: This will surely be necessary. Not just changing the CRS, but reprojecting one dataset to the other CRS. Otherwise the coordinates would not align, and the software complains about no overlap.

Comment: @AndreJ I think I was wrong. I've found online this document [UK Environment Agency LiDAR data](http://www.geostore.com/environment-agency/docs/Environment_Agency_LIDAR_Open_Data_FAQ_v5.pdf) which says in page 3 that all their products are projected on the `British National Grid` and that the elevation is measured relatively to the `Ordnance Datum Newlyn` (which basically just the MSL in Newlyn, Cornall, South West England). Besides, it's only the `DSM` produced by `ENVI LiDAR` which has wrong values of elevation (the original point cloud values are consistent with the `ASCII` one).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't even reproduce the inconsistency in the heights between the `.laz` and the `.asc` files, as the `.laz` file opened in `ENVI LiDAR` is now showing elevation values consistent with what shown in `QGIS` with the `.asc` file (~25m for the white building above).

As explained in this document [UK Environment Agency LiDAR Data](http://www.geostore.com/environment-agency/docs/Environment_Agency_LIDAR_Open_Data_FAQ_v5.pdf), both of these products are projected on the `British National Grid` and the elevation is measured relatively to the `Ordnance Datum Newlyn` (which is basically just the Mean-Sea-Level in Newlyn, Cornall, South West England).

Comment: What did you mean with "couldn't reproduce the inconsistency". What was the problem, then?

Comment: @AndreSilva I've just managed to reproduce the inconsistency in the height in `ENVI LiDAR`, I'll edit my answer later accordingly if necessary. So, when I open the `.laz` point cloud with `ENVI LiDAR` and set the projection to `EPSG=27700` the height is different from when I set directly the projection to the `British National Grid`. Obviously, before I was using the former projection, hence the inconsistency in the height shown in `ENVI LiDAR`. But, I still don't know why the difference in the height values! Knowing that both units are in meters unless the British National Grid<>EPSG:27700.

Comment: I got it now. I think you should edit your answer to clarify this. About the last sentence on your comment, check it and let us know also through an update in the answer. This way, future readers could benefit from this post if someone faces the same problem you had. Tks.